# How to submit a html page which comes a response to previous request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

Scenario:
in response to api request we get a html page as response, we need to accomplish the page with details and need to 'submit' that.

In JMeter:
-- I am able the to save response as a page to html
-- Need to submit page with one textField, one dropdown value

Is there possibility, that we can automate these with JMeter?

Thank you.

I tried my best, can any one please help on this.

Comment: Instead of sending HTML page, you can send what request being sent once you get the response from the API. 1. Send API Request 2. Receive API Response 3. Instead of saving that as a html, you need to save/know what request being sent next. 4. Extract that request using Post Processors and send it in the subsequent step.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have to extract the request using xpath extractor and try to send it in the subsequent request.

Comment: as i have mentioned, a complete webpage as response i am getting. I have the submit with few fields info.
can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just record your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), it is capable of capturing both GET and POST requests and converting them into corresponding [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

Alternative options of recording JMeter tests are [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) and [Badboy](http://www.badboysoftware.biz/docs/jmeter.htm).

---

If it misunderstood your query and you are asking about the ways of automatically detecting and submitting forms using random dropdown or radiobuttons values in JMeter test you can take a look at [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser)